# dynamial query in firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I am trying to dynamical query in firestore for <= and >= operator.
that is mean I wanna add each key and value dynamical to the query
but I getting  an error that it will not work on firebase.

> All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'FieldPath([price])' and 'FieldPath([meter])'.
> 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 780 pos 13: 'hasInequality == field'

My code:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late Query _query;
  final Map<String, dynamic> _filters = {
    'price': 500,
    'meter': 120,
  };
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items');
    for (var key in _filters.keys) {
      if (_filters[key] != null) {
        _query = _query.where(key, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _filters[key]);
      }
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _query.snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              DocumentSnapshot document = documents[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${document['price']}'),
                subtitle: Text(
                    '${document['meter']} m² / ${document['landMeter']} m²'),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

is there any way to work around this limitation?
or dynamic querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Firestore documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) it says:

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Your code is adding `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` (`>=`) conditions on both `price` and `meter` fields, which does not meet this limit.

The problem is not so much that you're building your query dynamically, but that you're trying to add `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` conditions on multiple fields, which Firestore doesn't support.

---

One options is to perform only one condition on the database, and do further filtering in your application code.

---

Another workaround is (as usual when dealing with NoSQL databases) to add additional data to allow the use-case, although I'm not sure if it applies here.

The closest I can think of, you could add a single field with both of the values:

```
price_meter: "500_120"
```

You could then do a `notEqual` query on this composite value, but it won't be easy to implement a double `>=` this way, so client-side filtering might be your only option for that.

Comment: thanks @FrankVanPuffelen
I will try first option

Comment: Why doesn't Google improve firebase to manage it?

Comment: Because Firestore has quite strict performance guarantees that the time a query takes does not depends on the number of documents it needs to consider, and there's currently no way to perform such a filter within that performance guarantee.

Comment: if I use first option I think I will get trouble with pagination?

Comment: You may need to read more data than you end up showing, which definitely affects pagination. There's no easy way around that, it's just more code and (typically) more  reads. If you require both this multi-field filter and pagination, there's no reasonable other way though.